# Linker script - Location counter and discard sections

Tags: gcc, assembly, ld, x86-16, linker-scripts

I am following [this](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/master/c_hello_world/) hello-world boot sector program, which has the following linker script :

```
ENTRY(mystart)
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x7c00;
  .text : {
    entry.o(.text)
    *(.text)
    *(.data)
    *(.rodata)
    __bss_start = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    __bss_end = .;
  }

  .sig : AT(ADDR(.text) + 512 - 2)
  {
      SHORT(0xaa55);
  }
  /DISCARD/ : {
    *(.eh_frame)
  }
  __stack_bottom = .;
  . = . + 0x1000;
  __stack_top = .;
}
```

Following is the `entry.S` :

```
.code16
.text
.global mystart
mystart:
    ljmp $0, $.setcs
.setcs:
    xor %ax, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $__stack_top, %esp
    cld
    call main
```

Following is the `main` function

```
void main(void) {
    int i;
    char s[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'};
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s); ++i) {
        __asm__ (
            "int $0x10" : : "a" ((0x0e << 8) | s[i])
        );
    }
    while (1) {
        __asm__ ("hlt");
    };
}
```

I was expecting the `__stack_top` to take the value of 0x8E00 (0x7C00 + 0x200 (512 bytes of boot sector) + 0x1000 (4KiB stack) ), but when I check the program in gdb, the instruction

```
mov $__stack_top, %esp
```

pushes 0x8c93 into %esp.

Why is this happening? Does `eh_frame` impact in any way or am I missing something here? Please help.

Comment: This is a guess, I don't have time to load this to try. After processing the `.text` section the VMA (Virtual memory address) was 0x7c91. When you emitted the .sig` section but only told that section to modify the LMA (load memory address) and pointed it at 0x7e00-2. After finishing the `.sig` section the VMA was incremented by 2 (you emitted 2 bytes 0xaa55) to 0x7c93 and the LMA was now 0x7e00. When you do `. = . + 0x1000` you are adding 0x1000 to the current VMA which is 0x7c93. 0x7c93+0x1000=0x8c93

Comment: To fix this you could set the VMA as well as the LMA when you output the `.sig` section. Does this work: `.sig 0x7dfe : AT(ADDR(.text) + 512 - 2)` . Alternatively you could just put `. = 0x7e00;` just before `__stack_bottom = .;`  so the VMA is advanced to 0x7e00.

Comment: @MichaelPetch : After reading your comments, I verified that the .text section is indeed ending at 0x7c93. Also both of your solution work. I also get it now that this whole problem exists because .text size is lesser than 510 bytes. Hence, even though LMA and VMA were same at the beginning of .text section, they become different during .sig section due to this difference in size. However, I am not completely clear on VMA and LMA. Does LMA refer to on-disk image address and VMA refer to address at runtime in RAM? Can you please clarify on VMA and DMA.

Comment: The VMA is the address the section will have when the output file is run. The LMA is the address at which the section will be loaded. There is documentation and examples on the GNU LD pages: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.33.1/ld/index.html#SEC_Contents . The VMA and LMA are described here:  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.33.1/ld/Basic-Script-Concepts.html#Basic-Script-Concepts

Comment: "0x1000 (16 MB stack)" -- This cannot be, because 16 MiB are not addressable in Real 86 Mode. Adding 1000h to an offset advances that offset by 4 KiB, so if you set sp to 8E00h you would have a 4 KiB stack.

Comment: @ecm : oops... correct. that was a typo from my side. Thanks for the suggestion. Corrected.